# SMB shared folder error when creating additional share on our SAN

Tags: server-message-block, shares

Okay, we have a SAN using Failover Cluster Management on a pair of 2008 servers.  We created shares on here before and they are usable.

Now when I go to create a new share I get the following error message:

"Flags for the SMB Shared folder cannot be configured.  This shared resource does not exist"

Does not allow me to create the share then.

Haven't been able to find any good docs out there to help me through this error.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it came down to a permissions issue on that particular folder I was working with.  I got it working now...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I found that the problem is related with security grants in the folder. You can find the complete detailed solution with print screens on my blog, here: http://blog.danielcosta.pt/?p=297

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Found the same problem and eventually found the permission problem.
I could not share the folder because there were some files way down the directory structure that I didn't have permission to.
Permissions were fine at the top level.
Took a copy of the files.
Took ownership and deleted the files then I could create the share